# Is it possible to add a canonical tag in an RSS feed?

Tags: rss, canonical-url

We are producing content and exposing it via RSS Feed for content syndication by other bloggers. The others are picking my content and syndicating it on their website, which is leading to duplicity.

Is it possible for me to add a canonical tag in the RSS Feed? If yes, is it going to impact on our website?

Comment: There is no canonical tag, however, there is a link tag. Are websites ignoring this link when they present your content?

Comment: Consider requiring a user sign-up with usernames and passwords. Add to this your acceptable use policy. It is common that unethical sites will use content without attribution which is a violation of copyright. You need to enforce this. This link is about protecting your RSS feed: https://perishablepress.com/protect-against-content-thieves/ It may not apply to your needs. Still worth a read. Cheers!!

Comment: yes they are not adding it..they are ignoring the link completely...

Comment: Have you considered using iframes for the content in your RSS feeds?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have nothing to worry about in general, since Google crawls sites daily, it will know that you have indeed placed the content first and will not ding you for duplicate content.

I would however suggest you add a delay to RSS feed for 2-3 days so you indeed get crawled first. Unfortunately you can not add any links that a site admin does not have access to remove manually.

Answer (score 1):

I would completely noIndex and nofollow it. Because IT is just an Asset providing no additional seo value, But producing dc.